# How to change the minSDK Version in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

While creating a new android project in eclipse 3.5, i have selected Android 2.1 Update1 as build target. But i forgot to give the mini SDK version. Now when the build the project, its giving a warning message "***WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2)***"

The application is running fine..but when i run that application is my Samsung Galaxy S which is having android 2.1, the application is behaving differently.

I have even tried adding
 `<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="7" />` in the manifest file..But still i am getting the warning message..

So how can i change the mini SDK of my project in eclipse to 7,so that i get the same result in my emulator and Mobile phone?

Thanks in advance
Shijilal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your manifest there should be something like this

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="int" />
```

Now just change the number to the desired version number. Additionally you should also change the value of the `target` in the `default.properties` file.

Comment: in the default.properties.. it was 7 only. but the application seems to be ignoring that and was using mini sdk 8.. Anyways after mentioning <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" /> in the manifest file..now its ohk..thanks again